# Do Nigerian citizens still need a visa to visit Turkey?

Tags: visas, turkey, nigerian-citizens

One of the guests at my hostel here in Georgia is a young guy from Nigeria and he asked me if he needs a visa to go to Turkey.

I did some searching on the Internet and found conflicting answers:

The article **[Visa regulations lifted with yet another nation](http://english.sabah.com.tr/Travel/2011/12/16/visa-regulations-lifted-with-yet-another-nation)** on sabah.com.tr says:

> **Nigeria is the newest addition to the countries in which visa regulations will be lifted with Turkey.**
>   Foreign Affairs Minister Ahmet Davutoğlu and Nigerian Foreign Affairs Minister Olugbenga Ashiru will be meeting at the Turkey-Africa Partnership Ministerial Review Conference and will sign a joint agreement to lift mutual visa regulations.

But the Turkish government page, **[Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)** says:

> **Nigeria:** Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey.

Is the Turkish visa page current or out-of-date? If the agreement is not yet in effect can anybody tell me when these new rules will begin?

Comment: It seems that the agreement is not in force yet (it was signed only a month ago). Apparently only holders of diplomatic passports can travel without a visa at the moment. I can't find any reliable source or even a tentative date, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in a comment, the agreement mentioned in that news article has not yet gone into effect. In fact there are several outstanding changes to Turkish visas which are pending but not yet active. There will be changes to quite a few countries' visas that go into effect on February 1st of 2012. That would be the earliest date I would expect the Nigerian agreement to be effective, but I don't know that it's scheduled for then and kind of doubt it will.

In short, at the moment he still needs a visa. No confirmation is available as to when the agreement with Nigeria will take effect.